# What are the Martin's Maximum consequences of Namba forcing?

Tags: set-theory, forcing

It is known that Namba forcing is stationary-preserving and hence can be used in the setting of Martin's Maximum. Does this result in any striking consequences?

Comment: Maybe the Strong Chang Conjecture?

Comment: Is the proof a relatively direct application of Namba forcing? Or is it more indirect? 

Comment: I added the forcing tag.

Comment: @Francois: Are you referring to Shelah's result that "Namba forcing is semiproper" implies SCC?

Comment: That's what I was wondering. I'd like an application with a proof along the lines of those in Baumgartner's great article on PFA. If the proof of the Strong Chang Conjecture is: MM implies Namba is
semi-proper which implies SCC, then I'm not satisfied.

Comment: Yes, that's the way the proof goes (via Shelah's result). I agree that this is not satisfactory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that I may have found a suitable candidate; namely, the result of
Konig and Yoshinobu that $MM$ implies that there are no $\omega_{1}$-regressive $\omega_{2}$-Kurepa trees. The proof seems to have the same relatively direct flavor as those in Baumgartner's $PFA$ article.

Answer (score 8):

Magidor's proof that MM implies that there are no *good* scales of length lambda^+ for lambda>cf(lambda)=w, utilizes a Namba-style forcing.

Answer (score 3):

Justin Moore asked a similar question a while ago, and I pointed him to my papers with Claverie and Doebler. Even though it doesn't exactly answer your question: Namba-like forcings (in the sense that they are stationary set preserving and make $\omega_2$ $\omega$-cofinal) have many applications in the presence of ${\sf MM}$. The most recent one is my proof with David Asperó that ${\sf MM}^{++}$ implies Woodin's $(*)$, see https://ivv5hpp.uni-muenster.de/u/rds/MM_implies_star.pdf .